# Merging monthly dates with customer and cost in R

Tags: r

How do I merge the each monthly dates and sales to each customer?

```
custid <- c(1,1,1,2,2,5,6,8,8,8)

date <- c(20130401,  20130403,  20130504,   20130508,   20130511,   20130716,   
      20130719, 20130423,   20130729,   20130707)

cost <- c(12,  41,  89, 45.5,   32.89,  74, 76, 12, 15.78,  10)

data <- data.frame(custid, date,cost)

data$date <- as.Date(as.character(data$date), "%Y%m%d") 

aggregate(cbind(total_cost_per_month=cost)~cbind(date=format(date, '%Y-%m')), cbind(custid=custid), data, sum) 

Error in prettyNum(.Internal(format(x, trim, digits, nsmall, width, 3L,  : 
                                  invalid 'trim' argument
```

I am trying to make my data similar to this output. Is it even possible to reformat more than 2 columns here? Aggregate functions works for merging/stacking the dates and cost

```
custid  date      monthlyCost
1       201304    53
1       201305    89
2       201305    78.39
5       201307    74
6       201307    76
8       201304    27.78
8       201307    10
```

Thanks!

Comment: `aggregate(cbind(monthlyCost=cost)~cbind(date=format(date, '%Y-%m'))+custid, data, sum)`

Comment: @sharp Try the code in the comment

Comment: @docendodiscimus It was quite similar. But now it is about adding another layer to the aggregation.There was no custid in the previous question.